# Canvas - floodfill leaves white pixels at edges

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors, flood-fill

I am creating a drawing app. I have succeeded to do everything. When I paint the image with a dark color, some white pixels appear at the edges. I tried to change the value of r + g + b and also alpha but no use. Can any one help me out? You can check the live site from [here](http://colorpeutic.com/product.php?id=14). Anyone who will help me, I shall grant 50 bounty to him/her. Thanks. This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initial = screen.width - 50;

    if (initial < 1000) {
        initial = 1000;
    }

    var firsttime = null;

    var colorYellow = {
        r: 255,
        g: 207,
        b: 51
    };

    var context;
    var canvasWidth = initial;
    var canvasHeight = initial;
    var myColor = colorYellow;
    var curColor = myColor;
    var outlineImage = new Image();
    var backgroundImage = new Image();
    var drawingAreaX = 0;
    var drawingAreaY = 0;
    var drawingAreaWidth = initial;
    var drawingAreaHeight = initial;
    var colorLayerData;
    var outlineLayerData;
    var totalLoadResources = 2;
    var curLoadResNum = 0;
    var undoarr = new Array();
    var redoarr = new Array();

    function history(command) { // handles undo/redo button events.
        var data;
        if (command === "redo") {
            data = historyManager.redo(); // get data for redo
        } else
        if (command === "undo") {
            data = historyManager.undo(); // get data for undo
        }
        if (data !== undefined) { // if data has been found
            setColorLayer(data); // set the data
        }
    }

    // sets colour layer and creates copy into colorLayerData
    function setColorLayer(data) {
        context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
        colorLayerData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        context.drawImage(outlineImage, 0, 0, drawingAreaWidth, drawingAreaHeight);
    }

    // Clears the canvas.
    function clearCanvas() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    }



    // Draw the elements on the canvas
    function redraw() {
        uc = 0;
        rc = 0;
        var locX,
            locY;

        // Make sure required resources are loaded before redrawing
        if (curLoadResNum < totalLoadResources) {
            return; // To check if images are loaded successfully or not.
        }

        clearCanvas();
        // Draw the current state of the color layer to the canvas
        context.putImageData(colorLayerData, 0, 0);

        historyManager.push(context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight));
        redoarr = new Array();
        // Draw the background
        context.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        // Draw the outline image on top of everything. We could move this to a separate 
        //   canvas so we did not have to redraw this everyime.
        context.drawImage(outlineImage, 0, 0, drawingAreaWidth, drawingAreaHeight);
    };

    function matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a) {

        return (r + g + b < 50 && a >= 50);
    };

    function matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB) {

        var r = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos],
            g = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1],
            b = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2],
            a = outlineLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3];

        // If current pixel of the outline image is black
        if (matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a)) {
            return false;
        }

        r = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos];
        g = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1];
        b = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2];

        // If the current pixel matches the clicked color
        if (r === startR && g === startG && b === startB) {
            return true;
        }

        // If current pixel matches the new color
        if (r === curColor.r && g === curColor.g && b === curColor.b) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };

    function colorPixel(pixelPos, r, g, b, a) {
        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos] = r;
        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1] = g;
        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2] = b;
        colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3] = a !== undefined ? a : 255;
    };

    function floodFill(startX, startY, startR, startG, startB) {

        document.getElementById('color-lib-1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('color-lib-2').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('color-lib-3').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('color-lib-4').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('color-lib-5').style.display = "none";

        change = false;

        var newPos,
            x,
            y,
            pixelPos,
            reachLeft,
            reachRight,
            drawingBoundLeft = drawingAreaX,
            drawingBoundTop = drawingAreaY,
            drawingBoundRight = drawingAreaX + drawingAreaWidth - 1,
            drawingBoundBottom = drawingAreaY + drawingAreaHeight - 1,
            pixelStack = [
                [startX, startY]
            ];

        while (pixelStack.length) {

            newPos = pixelStack.pop();
            x = newPos[0];
            y = newPos[1];

            // Get current pixel position
            pixelPos = (y * canvasWidth + x) * 4;

            // Go up as long as the color matches and are inside the canvas
            while (y >= drawingBoundTop && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
                y -= 1;
                pixelPos -= canvasWidth * 4;
            }

            pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
            y += 1;
            reachLeft = false;
            reachRight = false;

            // Go down as long as the color matches and in inside the canvas
            while (y <= drawingBoundBottom && matchStartColor(pixelPos, startR, startG, startB)) {
                y += 1;

                colorPixel(pixelPos, curColor.r, curColor.g, curColor.b);

                if (x > drawingBoundLeft) {
                    if (matchStartColor(pixelPos - 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
                        if (!reachLeft) {
                            // Add pixel to stack
                            pixelStack.push([x - 1, y]);
                            reachLeft = true;
                        }

                    } else if (reachLeft) {
                        reachLeft = false;
                    }
                }

                if (x < drawingBoundRight) {
                    if (matchStartColor(pixelPos + 4, startR, startG, startB)) {
                        if (!reachRight) {
                            // Add pixel to stack
                            pixelStack.push([x + 1, y]);
                            reachRight = true;
                        }
                    } else if (reachRight) {
                        reachRight = false;
                    }
                }

                pixelPos += canvasWidth * 4;
            }
        }
    };

    // Start painting with paint bucket tool starting from pixel specified by startX and startY
    function paintAt(startX, startY) {

        var pixelPos = (startY * canvasWidth + startX) * 4,
            r = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos],
            g = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 1],
            b = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 2],
            a = colorLayerData.data[pixelPos + 3];

        if (r === curColor.r && g === curColor.g && b === curColor.b) {
            // Return because trying to fill with the same color
            return;
        }

        if (matchOutlineColor(r, g, b, a)) {
            // Return because clicked outline
            return;
        }

        floodFill(startX, startY, r, g, b);

        redraw();
    };

    // Add mouse event listeners to the canvas
    function createMouseEvents() {

        $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e) {

            // Mouse down location
            var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
                mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

            // assuming that the mouseX and mouseY are the mouse coords.
            if (this.style.width) { // make sure there is a width in the style 
                // (assumes if width is there then height will be too
                var w = Number(this.style.width.replace("px", "")); // warning this will not work if size is not in pixels
                var h = Number(this.style.height.replace("px", "")); // convert the height to a number
                var pixelW = this.width; // get  the canvas resolution
                var pixelH = this.height;
                mouseX = Math.floor((mouseX / w) * pixelW); // convert the mouse coords to pixel coords
                mouseY = Math.floor((mouseY / h) * pixelH);
            }

            if ((mouseY > drawingAreaY && mouseY < drawingAreaY + drawingAreaHeight) && (mouseX <= drawingAreaX + drawingAreaWidth)) {
                paintAt(mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        });
    };

    resourceLoaded = function() {

        curLoadResNum += 1;
        //if (curLoadResNum === totalLoadResources) {
        createMouseEvents();
        redraw();
        //}
    };

    var historyManager = (function() { // Anon for private (closure) scope
        var uBuffer = []; // this is undo buff
        var rBuffer = []; // this is redo buff
        var currentState = undefined; // this holds the current history state
        var undoElement = undefined;
        var redoElement = undefined;
        var manager = {
            UI: { // UI interface just for disable and enabling redo undo buttons
                assignUndoButton: function(element) {
                    undoElement = element;
                    this.update();
                },
                assignRedoButton: function(element) {
                    redoElement = element;
                    this.update();
                },
                update: function() {
                    if (redoElement !== undefined) {
                        redoElement.disabled = (rBuffer.length === 0);
                    }
                    if (undoElement !== undefined) {
                        undoElement.disabled = (uBuffer.length === 0);
                    }
                }
            },
            reset: function() {
                uBuffer.length = 0;
                rBuffer.length = 0;
                currentState = undefined;
                this.UI.update();
            },
            push: function(data) {
                if (currentState !== undefined) {
                    var same = true
                    for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                        if (data.data[i] !== currentState.data[i]) {
                            same = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (same) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (currentState !== undefined) {
                    uBuffer.push(currentState);
                }
                currentState = data;
                rBuffer.length = 0;
                this.UI.update();
            },
            undo: function() {
                if (uBuffer.length > 0) {
                    if (currentState !== undefined) {
                        rBuffer.push(currentState);
                    }
                    currentState = uBuffer.pop();
                }
                this.UI.update();
                return currentState; // return data or unfefined
            },
            redo: function() {
                if (rBuffer.length > 0) {
                    if (currentState !== undefined) {
                        uBuffer.push(currentState);
                    }
                    currentState = rBuffer.pop();
                }
                this.UI.update();
                return currentState;
            },
        }
        return manager;
    })();

    function start() {

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
        canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
        document.getElementById('canvasDiv').appendChild(canvas);

        if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== "undefined") {
            canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
        }
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        backgroundImage.onload = resourceLoaded();
        backgroundImage.src = "images/t.png";

        outlineImage.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(outlineImage, drawingAreaX, drawingAreaY, drawingAreaWidth, drawingAreaHeight);

            try {
                outlineLayerData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            } catch (ex) {
                window.alert("Application cannot be run locally. Please run on a server.");
                return;
            }
            clearCanvas();
            colorLayerData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            resourceLoaded();
        };
        outlineImage.src = "images/products/<?php echo $product['product_image']; ?>";
    };

    if (historyManager !== undefined) {
        // only for visual feedback and not required for the history manager to function.
        historyManager.UI.assignUndoButton(document.querySelector("#undo-button"));
        historyManager.UI.assignRedoButton(document.querySelector("#redo-button"));
    }

    getColor = function() {

    };
</script>
```

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest two changes:

1. Blend pixel & fill color instead of hard override
2. Restrict fill area based on intensity gradient changes instead of simple threshold

Filling in horizontal and vertical direction until the sign of the intensity gradient flips from either + to - OR - to + lets us fill the whole area including 'half' of the black border. By inspecting the gradient we just make sure not to overstep the intensity minimum and thus avoid filling a neighboring area.

Have a look at the following demo:

```js
// Get pixel intensity:
function getIntensity(data, i) {
  return data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2];
}

// Set pixel color:
function setColor(data, i, r, g, b) {
  data[i] &= r;
  data[i + 1] &= g;
  data[i + 2] &= b;
}

// Fill a horizontal line:
function fill(x, y, data, width, r, g, b) {
  var i_start = y * (width << 2);
  var i = i_start + (x << 2);
  var i_end = i_start + (width << 2);
  var i_intensity = getIntensity(data, i);

  // Horizontal line to the right:
  var prev_gradient = 0;
  var prev_intensity = i_intensity;
  for (var j = i; j < i_end; j += 4) {
    var intensity = getIntensity(data, j);
    gradient = intensity - prev_intensity;
    prev_intensity = intensity;
    if ((prev_gradient > 0 && gradient < 0) || (prev_gradient < 0 && gradient > 0)) break;
    if (gradient != 0) prev_gradient = gradient;

    setColor(data, j, 255, 0, 0);
  }

  // Horizontal line to the left:
  prev_gradient = 0;
  prev_intensity = i_intensity;
  for (var j = i - 4; j > i_start; j -= 4) {
    var intensity = getIntensity(data, j);
    gradient = intensity - prev_intensity;
    prev_intensity = intensity;
    if ((prev_gradient > 0 && gradient < 0) || (prev_gradient < 0 && gradient > 0)) break;
    if (gradient != 0) prev_gradient = gradient;

    setColor(data, j, 255, 0, 0);
  }
}

// Demo canvas:
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Fill horizontal line on click:
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = event.clientX - rect.left | 0;
  var y = event.clientY - rect.top | 0;

  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  fill(x, y, imageData.data, imageData.width);
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
});

// Load a sample image:
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('load', event => {
  context.drawImage(event.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAACCAIAAAABwbG5AAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBnbm9tZS1zY3JlZW5zaG907wO/PgAAACZJREFUCJlj+I8Kbt68mZeXd/PmTbgIw38MsG/fvoKCgqdPn0K4ACAfPGrloJp1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

You can improve the performance by tracing only one color channel instead of summing all three for your `getIntensity` function.

Also, you would need to deal with 'clearing' an already filled area before filling it again with another color, due to the blending mode.

You could e. g. keep a single-channel grayscale image data array of the background image in memory and use it as the source image for your fill algorithm.

It might be even more performant to (manually or automatically) transform all your grayscale images to 1-bit outlines with binary boundaries and use them as the source for your floodfill algorithm, blending the result smoothly with the grayscale image.

Comment: I spend a lot of time writing this answer; writing your code would just be too much. However, if you have specific questions about how to proceed, go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "white" spots left out aren't actually white as there's a tiny gradient going on between white and black. Try giving it some leeway around these lines:

```
 if ((r <= curColor.r + 10 && r >= curColor.r - 10)  && (r >= curColor.g - 10 && r <= curColor.g + 10) && (b >= curColor.b - 10 && b <= curColor.b + 10)) {
        return false;
    }
```

You can modify the 10 factor until it looks good. Just tweak it until it's okay.
(Might be bad code , I just woke up but you should get the picture :D )

You could also preprocess the image in a separate buffer and reduce the number of colors. That way it's easier to fill the beginning of gradients, thus reducing or elimitating the undesired effect you are describing.

Comment: where do I change this line?

Comment: Under the "// If the current pixel matches the clicked color". Should work slightly better.

Comment: I did it but it is the same. No effect :( Still white dots appearing.

Comment: Even if you tweak the parameter ?

Comment: Yes I tweaked the parameter upto 30.

Comment: Hmm you could create a fiddle with the image and all, it would be easier to help

Comment: I don't know how to create a fiddle but I can send you a copy of my local project. What do you say?

Comment: Sure, just post it somewhere

Comment: Are you comfortable in PHP?

Comment: I have uploaded the file product.php over here http://speedy.sh/WtEBP/product.rar

Comment: It's incomplete and I don't really have that much time to patch it to work. If you require help on this, please create a fiddle here with your code https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Okay let me send you my complete project along with database. Okay?

Comment: @overburn You accidentally wrote `(r >= curColor.g - 10 && r <= curColor.g + 10)` instead of `(g >= curColor.g - 10 && g <= curColor.g + 10)`. Not sure how much difference it'll make, but that could help.

Comment: Oh right, yeah i had just woken up, i think my brain was loading.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest it's not really your drawing program's fault so much as the fault of the images being drawn on. The 'white' pixels are actually pale grey, a side effect of the brush tool used to draw the lines in the images. There are two ways around this:

1. To remove all pale grey pixels from the image and make them white. Using a color select tool and a pencil tool will fix that. The only side effect is that the lines at some points may seem a bit jerky.
2. To give some leniency when it comes to what colors get painted over. So, instead of just replacing straight white, replace pale greys as well. Any color up to around #CCC (or rgb(204, 204, 204)) should be colored over.

The code for option two is as follows:

```
if(r >= 204 && g >= 204 && b >= 204 && r === g && g === b){
    return true;
}
```

This simply checks if the pixel is a light greyscale color and returns true if so. Use this instead of your outline color checking function.

Answer (score 1):

Your check for the outline is simply too strict, marking light gray pixels as ones you cannot color in.  I simply tweaked your threshholds:

```
function matchOutlineColor (r,g,b,a,e) {
  return a >= 150;
}
```

Notice my much higher numbers for the white value and alpha.  You could maybe tweak this further but this looks good to me.  Here are some before and after photos:

Before (zoomed in 200%)
[image]

After (zoomed in 200%)
[image]